# Sqlite error: No such table main.table_name exists

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

In my UWP app, I am creating tables on the App Start in the sqlite db. Also, I have written various Alter commands wherein I check if the installed app contains the respective columns in Customertbl and rename the Customertbl table as Customertbl_old and create new table Customertbl and finally I store all rows from the Customertbl_old table into Customertbl table. And then I drop table Customertbl_old.
Now, up to this part everything works correctly but, When I try to delete/ insert a row in OwnerTbl it throws an exception saying

**Sqlite error: No such table main.Customertbl_old exists.**

```
//**Code where a column name is updated by creating new table**
string tableCommand = "PRAGMA table_info(Recordings)"; 
SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);
SqliteDataReader query = createTable.ExecuteReader(); 
tableCommand = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = off; " + " 
BEGIN TRANSACTION; " +
" ALTER TABLE Customertbl RENAME TO _Customertbl_old; " +
" CREATE TABLE Customertbl ( " + " ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " CustomerName NVARCHAR(100) NULL, " + " Password NVARCHAR(100) NULL, " + " 
pkID INTEGER NULL, " + " ActivityName NVARCHAR(255) NULL);" +
 " INSERT INTO Customertbl(Name,Password) " + " SELECT Name,Password " + " 
FROM _Customertbl_old ;" + " COMMIT; " + " PRAGMA foreign_keys=on; " + " 
DROP TABLE 
_Customertbl_old";

// **code where exception occur**
using (SqliteConnection db = new 
SqliteConnection("Filename=" + App.dbName)) 
{ 
db.Open(); 
SqliteCommand deleteCommand = new SqliteCommand(); 
try 
{ 
    deleteCommand.Connection = db; 
    deleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Ownertbl where fkId = @id";  
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);  
    deleteCommand.ExecuteReader()//here the exception occur ;  
    db.Close(); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Which is expected, because you dropped it? Without knowing more about the schema, it's hard to tell what's wrong. The exact statement that leads to the error would also be helpful.

Comment: Hi, the exception is not expected because after deleting table Customertbl_old  from my sqlite I am not trying to access it any way. Instead when I execute queries related to dfferent table it throws an error that tells me that: Error:  No such table main.Customertbl_old exists.

Comment: _"I am not trying to access it any way"_ Not any way _you are aware of_. SQLite seems to think differently, though. Do you have Foreign Key relationships between those tables?

Comment: _Do you have Foreign Key relationships between those tables?_  Yes 
but how does that matter, any way i am deleting old table. Please help me understand this.

Comment: You need to show us your schema. My bet is currently on some constraint issue, but that's really only a wild guess without knowing the schema. Please use the [edit] link to amend your question. Don't put it in the comments.

Comment: Can you please tell us, why you copy & drop? It doesn't make sense to me and seems to be the source of your problems. I guess Ownertbl will still reference the dropped table. That means you either have to update references or null them. But then you can as well just not copy & drop ...

Comment: Which version of SQLite are you using? Recent versions have updated the ALTER TABLE command to automatically rename certain things (including PK references). This means the OLD way of altering tables (rename, create new, move data) may no longer work UNLESS you use `pragma legacy_alter_table=ON`. See [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). Alternatively, you may JUST be able to alter the table directly.

Comment: @TripeHound  SQLite still does not allow changing column properties and constraints on an existing table, thus it still requires the long, explicit change procedure for most changes.  Being aware of the new behavior is necessary, and it requires a change to the order of the steps, but it does not make most "direct" changes possible (besides renaming). `pragma legacy_alter_table=ON` is not necessary if the change script order is updated.  These details are found in the [same link](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) you shared.

Comment: @Shakita  Do you have triggers that reference the original table?  Since you are renaming the old table, those references will also be changed so that when the old-renamed table is deleted, the triggers will remain with bad references.  As TripeHound pointed out (despite mischaracterizing some behavior), you should use the new order for the change script... do NOT rename the old table first.  See the cautions and suggested order in the [online docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Comment: @Fildor  SQLite does not allow direct changes to most table and column properties.  The standard procedure in SQLite is to "copy & drop".

Comment: @CPerkins I'm aware _many/most_ changes still need the "long" way. The key part of the comment remains: IF the OP is using a recent version, they need to know the behaviour has changed and either need to reinstate the legacy behaviour (or, perhaps, change the commands).

Comment: @CPerkins I am aware of that. Yet, OP did not show any alters outside the renaming ... that's why I asked.

Comment: @Fildor  But that's the whole point... there are *no* ALTER commands besides renaming in sqlite.  The only way to know what the OP is trying to change would be to see the original DDL (i.e. schema definition statements), but that is not included.  I was simply answering your question "why".

Comment: @CPerkins ah. I meant "alter" as in "change schema" not literally "ALTER TABLE"

Comment: Yes, but fyi in my work around I did not use **pragma legacy_alter_table=ON** as metioned by @TripeHound. I used ( create new, move data, Drop old, Rename new with old name)

Comment: The key, as I understand it, is foreign-key references in other tables. If you rename a table to `_old` then any FK references _in other tables_ will now get renamed as well (this didn't use to happen). When you then create a new table with the original name, copy the data and delete the `_old` table, the FK references are left dangling. Doing create/copy/drop/rename means `table_new` gets renamed to `table` but because there are no FK references to `_new`, nothing else is affected.

Answer (score 10):

### TL;DR

If a previously-working use of `ALTER TABLE...` has broken due to upgrading SQLite to version 3.26 or later, a "quick-fix" is to use `PRAGMA legacy_alter_table=ON` before making those changes. However, it is probably better to re-organise the commands (*see "**The Safe Way**"*). If you are starting a new project with a post-3.26 version of SQLite, I would definitely recommend using the "*The Safe Way*" and avoiding the `PRAGMA`.

### What Happened

Your problem arose because of changes made to SQLite's `ALTER TABLE` command in versions **3.25.0** (2018-09-15) and **3.26.0** (2018-12-01). For the official documentation, see [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) on the SQLite website.

Prior to this version, renaming a table (e.g. from `MY_TABLE` to `A_BETTER_NAMED_TABLE`) *only* changed the name of the table. Any *references* to that table (i.e. in Foreign Key (FK) constraints or triggers) were *not* renamed. If the goal was to *only* rename the table, this could reasonably be regarded as a bug, since there is no (easy, official) way of altering those references, and you would be left with an inconsistent database.

The above changes "fixed" this issue by propagating changes to a table's name into any such references. You could thus rename a table that was referenced by FK constraints or triggers and be left with a consistent database.

### When it Causes Problems

The OP's problem arises – indirectly – due to the very limited ability (when compared to a non-Lite database engine) of the `ALTER TABLE` command. In SQLite, all it can do is change the name of the table, the name of a column, or add new columns (to the "end" of a row). If you needed to do anything more complicated than that to a table, you had to get "inventive" (essentially, create a new replacement table and populate it from the old table). However, there are two ways of doing this, and one of them is "broken" by the above changes "*trying to be more helpful*".

### The Safe Way

- Create a new (e.g. `MY_TABLE_NEW`) with all the new properties you need.
- Migrate the existing data from `MY_TABLE` to `MY_TABLE_NEW` (adding default/missing values as appropriate).
- Delete the original table `MY_TABLE`. At this point, any FK constraints and triggers that refer to `MY_TABLE` would fail, but that doesn't matter.
- Use `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE_NEW RENAME TO MY_TABLE` to change the name of the new, correctly formatted table back to that of the original table. Any FK constraints/triggers references will now be satisfied again (assuming they are not to columns that were removed!)

The above will work both before and after the change. Before the change, no heed is paid to FK constraints/triggers; after the change, there will be no references to `MY_TABLE_NEW` so nothing will be propagated.

### The Broken Way

Before the change, the following procedure would work equally well:

- Use `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE RENAME TO MY_TABLE_OLD`. At this point, *in the old version* any FK constaints/triggers would be inconsistent, but that doesn't matter.
- Create a *replacement* table `MY_TABLE` with all the new properties you need. Any references will now be satisfied.
- Migrate the existing data from `MY_TABLE_OLD` to `MY_TABLE` (adding default/missing values as appropriate).
- Delete the original (but renamed) table `MY_TABLE_OLD`.

The problem arises with the new version because it will rename any references to the original table (`MY_TABLE`) so that they now reference the about-to-be-deleted table (`MY_TABLE_OLD`). None of the other steps will affect these references, so you are left with an inconsistent database (references to the non-existent `MY_TABLE_OLD`).

### The Fix

Either change the order of the table-manipulation steps to those in **The Safe Way** or – as documented on the [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) page – issue the command `PRAGMA legacy_alter_table=ON` before the `ALTER TABLE` command. This will prevent the "improved" behaviour from renaming references to `MY_TABLE` to `MY_TABLE_OLD`.

Comment: it would be nice if you could prefix your post with TL;DR: 
use PRAGMA legacy_alter_table=ON

Comment: @Max After a bit of deliberation, I have done so... however, in most cases I would recommend re-ordering the commands so the `pragma` is not needed.

Comment: I'd already renamed a table the old way and it took hours to fix because I didn't have enough experience to realize at first that the referencing tables would also have to be replaced, not just the table that had been copied wrong.